# Adding column header after each groupby a matrix in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

There is a matrix I have like:

```
id name score 
1    A    5   
2    B    5   
1    A    4   
4    C    2 
2    B    4
```

What I am doing is to grouping by the matrix based on id and name and sorted decreased in ssrs 2008 rdl and the output becomes:

```
id name score
1   A   9
2   B   9
4   C   2
```

What I need to do is to repeat the column header before each group by like:

```
Score:9
id name 
1  A
2  B
Score:2
id name
4  C
```

I could not find how to do it. I appreciate if someone helps. Best regards.

Comment: What is the group? It is not id cause in your exapected results 1 and 2 id's are in the same group.

Comment: id and name together is used in order to group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add Row Group => Group by : Score and Tick Add Group Header.
2. Delete 1st Column and 1st Row. Now your table should be like this

[image]

3. Fill in required info accordingly.

Expression on 1st row should be : `="Score : " + CStr(Fields!score.Value)`

Then your table design should be like this:

[image]

4. And here is the result:

[image]